# sudo apt-get command not found

Tags: apt

I cant run apt-get update or anything involves apt-get command. I tried dpkg --configure -a and this is what it said.

```
root@lxoric-AOD270:/home/lxoric# sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up google-chrome-stable (38.0.2125.122-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.154.1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 28, in <module>
import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
import apt_pkg
  ImportError: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12: invalid ELF header
  dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
  Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
  In file "/usr/share/menu/libreoffice-impress", at (or in the definition that ends at) line 18:
  [Desktop Entry]
          ^
  Unexpected end of line.
  Skipping file because of errors...
  /usr/share/menu/ixconn_config: 1: /usr/share/menu/ixconn_config: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
  /usr/share/menu/ixconn_folder: 1: /usr/share/menu/ixconn_folder: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
  /usr/share/menu/ixconn: 1: /usr/share/menu/ixconn: Syntax error: word unexpected  (expecting ")")
  In file "/usr/share/menu/libreoffice-calc", at (or in the definition that ends at) line 2:
  ~\ekVL    I٤��{S�9<f��}QL�Nm���@)�%8���
                                     ^
  Unexpected end of line.
  Skipping file because of errors...
  In file "/usr/share/menu/libreoffice-calc", at (or in the definition that ends at) line 1:
  command=" META-INF/��PPK��dEMETA-INF/MANIFEST.MFE�M
                                                         �0D������m-j�G{�"      icon="" needs="PK" package="libreoffice-calc" sectio" title=""
     ^
  Expected: """
  install-menu: /etc/menu-methods/openbox: aborting
  update-menus[15714]: Script /etc/menu-methods/openbox returned error status 1.
  Errors were encountered while processing:
   google-chrome-stable
   update-notifier-common
  root@lxoric-AOD270:/home/lxoric#
```

Comment: ehm I see a big flaw here: you are logged in as ROOT. So why are you still using "sudo"? Either you are root and use apt-get or you are not root and use sudo. Are you sure you are using Ubuntu as you should use it? I doubt using root with sudo is a very bright idea.

Answer (score 0):

Launch (Synaptic Package Manager), type- apt - in quick search box, in the list you will see- apt, right click and choose (Mark for installation), then click the apply button at the top, If apt is already installed, choose (Mark for complete removal) and click the apply button, after complete removal you need to reinstall apt and reboot system.